# C++ Function with iterators from templated container

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, iterator

I'm trying to write a basic bucket sort. I have a function that takes in the begin and end iterators for a vector. I need to have the vector's value_type templated so that I can use it to create a vector of buckets for the sort (using std::numeric_limits).
The function is meant for T that's no bigger than short ints.

Here's the function I've written:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator forwardIterator;
void bucketSort(forwardIterator begin, forwardIterator end) {
  std::vector<unsigned> bucketVec(std::numeric_limits<T>::max() + 1, 0);
  for (auto it = begin; it != end; it++)
    bucketVec[*it]++;
  auto it = begin;
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < bucketVec.size(); j++)
    for (unsigned k = 0; k < bucketVec[j]; k++)
      *it++ = j;
}
```

when I try to compile this with g++ and -std=c++11, -O3 flags I get the following error messages:

```
bucketSort.cpp:14:17: error: variable or field 'bucketSort' declared void
bucketSort.cpp:14:17: error: 'forwardIterator' was not declared in this scope
bucketSort.cpp:14:40: error: 'forwardIterator' was not declared in this scope
bucketSort.cpp: in function 'int main()':
bucketSort.cpp:55:46: error: 'bucketSort' was not declared in this scope
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this so that it works.

Comment: Template variables are not possible pre-C++14.

Comment: `bucketVec(std::numeric_limits<T>::max() + 1, 0)` seems very wrong. If `T` is unsigned your vector will have zero elements, and if `T` is signed the first argument will be a large negative number (and signed int rollover is undefined behavior).

Comment: This function isn't intended to work with any T that's larger than 16 bits. I had written that in my question initially but edited it and forgot to put that back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::iterator_traits` can help you determine the value type given an iterator type.

```
template<typename forwardIterator>
void bucketSort(forwardIterator begin, forwardIterator end) {
  using T = typename std::iterator_traits<forwardIterator>::value_type;
  std::vector<unsigned> bucketVec(std::numeric_limits<T>::max() + 1, 0);
  for (auto it = begin; it != end; it++)
    bucketVec[*it]++;
  auto it = begin;
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < bucketVec.size(); j++)
    for (unsigned k = 0; k < bucketVec[j]; k++)
      *it++ = j;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I didn't know about iterator_traits or that use of the "using" keyword. I shall have to read more about both of those.

Comment: `using` in that sense is like `typedef` except that it's easier to see what you're declaring, and `using` can form a template alias, as in `template <typename T> using myvec = std::vector<T, my_custom_allocator>; myvec<int> v;`.

Comment: I found that this function only works for unsigned types. To get it to work for signed types I have to subtract std::numeric_limits<T>::min() from the size for bucketVec, and from j in the last line.

Comment: and also within the index for bucketVec in the first for-loop.